# splash screen before webview loads in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an app that uses webview but before loading it I need an splashscreen that checks if there is internet connection and if there isn't it shows an Snackbar in splashscreen. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: This tutorial might help: [How to Check Internet Connection in Flutter?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help. I achieved this in my personal project.

As you can see am using internet_connection_checker and whenever the internet is down I do a retry which was achieved by calling a `restart` widget in the main method to safely perform a restart whenever the internet is restored

1. Splash Page

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:airduka/main.dart';
import 'package:airduka/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:airduka/widgets/color.dart';
import 'package:airduka/widgets/custom_navigations.dart';
import 'package:airduka/widgets/small_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';


class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title, description, time;
  final UserModel? user;
  final List<dynamic>? listMsg;
  const SplashPage({Key? key, this.listMsg, required this.title, required this.description, required this.time, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  Timer? timer;

  Future<InternetConnectionStatus> dataConnection() async{
    InternetConnectionStatus statusMain = InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected;
    final StreamSubscription<InternetConnectionStatus> listener =
    InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen(
          (InternetConnectionStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
          case InternetConnectionStatus.connected:
         statusMain = InternetConnectionStatus.connected;
            break;
          case InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected:
            statusMain = InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected;
            break;
        }
      },
    );

    // close listener after 30 seconds, so the program doesn't run forever
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    await listener.cancel();
    return statusMain;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer(
     const Duration(seconds: 5),() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        PageTransition(
            child: FutureBuilder<InternetConnectionStatus>(
                future: dataConnection(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  switch(snapshot.connectionState){
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Scaffold(
                        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00639E),
                        body: Center(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assets/animations/jety.gif",
                            height: 200,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    default:
                      if(snapshot.hasError)
                        return Scaffold(
                          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00639E),
                          body: Center(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/animations/jety.gif",
                              height: 200,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      else if(snapshot.data ==  InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected)
                        return Scaffold(
                          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00639E),
                          body: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/animations/jety.gif",
                                  height: 200,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SmallTextWidget(text: "You seem to be offline", color: AppColors.whiteThemeColor,),
                              const SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: (){
                                  RestartWidget.restartApp(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 45,
                                  width: 100,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      color: AppColors.whiteThemeColor
                                  ),
                                  child: const Center(child: Text("Retry", style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blackThemeColor, fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      else  Scaffold(
                          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00639E),
                          body: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/animations/jety.gif",
                                  height: 200,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SmallTextWidget(text: "Something wrong happened!", color: AppColors.whiteThemeColor,),
                              const SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: (){
                                  RestartWidget.restartApp(context); //call restart here
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 45,
                                  width: 100,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      color: AppColors.whiteThemeColor
                                  ),
                                  child: const Center(child: Text("Retry", style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blackThemeColor, fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      return CustomNavigation(msgList: widget.listMsg, user: widget.user,);
                  }

                }),
            type: PageTransitionType.fade))
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00639E),
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/animations/jety.gif",
          height: 200,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. Restart Widget in the main method

```
class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestartWidget({required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartWidgetState>()!.restartApp();
  }

  @override
  _RestartWidgetState createState() => _RestartWidgetState();
}

class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyedSubtree(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this plugin**
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

```
Future<bool> checkInternet() async {
      var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        return true;
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

**Use it like this**

```
  if (!(await checkInternet())) {
        ///show your snackBar here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker) for internet check

```
bool result = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
if(result == true) {
   print('YAY! Free cute dog pics!');
} else {
   print('No internet :( Reason:');
}
```

call this code in init method in SplashScreen